# Angular 7 select option selected executed twice

Tags: angular, angular7

I have this template

```
<select
      [(ngModel)]="currentServer.environment"
      class="form-control form-control-sm component-form-control-color"
      id="inputGroupSelect01">
      <option
        *ngFor="let environment of environments"
        [ngValue]="environment"
        [selected]="myFunction()"
        >{{ environment.Name }}
      </option>
</select>
```

If in my controller the myFunction() contains à console.log() and if my environment array contains 4 elements, the console.log will be executed 8 times.

Why ?

Comment: add your `myFunction()` too

Comment: also tell the story, what you want to do? show your class methods

Comment: Now there is only a console.log in that function to check how many time it was executed. I want to achieve what Mariano Calcagno has stated

Comment: you have to show that how you are getting `environments` otherwise it would be much difficult to detect the problem? Either your `environments` array is being initialized twice!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [compareWith] as bellow

```
<select
      [(ngModel)]="currentServer.environment"  [compareWith]="compareFn"
      class="form-control form-control-sm component-form-control-color"
      id="inputGroupSelect01">
      <option
        *ngFor="let environment of environments"
        [ngValue]="environment"     
        >{{ environment.Name }}
      </option>
</select>
```

And in your ts file add following function

```
compareFn(c1, c2): boolean {
    return c1 && c2 ? c1.id=== c2.id: c1 === c2;
}
```

Here "id" should be unique property name based on which you need to do comparison of the objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That's great

Answer (score 1):

`[(ngModel)]` is supposed to set the `selected` option, you dont have to use `[selected]`. If you are dealing with Object comparison, you can provide a comparator using `compareWith`, or use the exact object reference as value:

```
// Using exact object reference as value
currentServer.environment = environments.filter(e => e.name === 'dev')[0];
```

---

```
// Using custom comparator
<select
      [(ngModel)]="currentServer.environment"
      [compareWith]="compareFn"
      class="form-control form-control-sm component-form-control-color"
      id="inputGroupSelect01">
      <option
        *ngFor="let environment of environments"
        [ngValue]="environment"
        >{{ environment.Name }}</option
      >
</select>
```

---

```
compareFn(c1: any, c2:any): boolean {     
 return c1 && c2 ? c1.name === c2.name : c1 === c2; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I would validate both answers if I could.

Answer (score 0):

it's the changeDetection (you can try using changeDetectionStrategy.OnPush but you need to read about). In development mode checks are double. I don't know what "myFunction()" do, but why not use "[selected]="environment===currentServer.environment""?

```
<select
          [(ngModel)]="currentServer.environment"
          class="form-control form-control-sm component-form-control-color"
          id="inputGroupSelect01"
        >
          <option
            *ngFor="let environment of environments"
            [ngValue]="environment"
            [selected]="environment===currentServer.environment"
            >{{ environment.Name }}</option
          >
    </select>
```

Comment: "In development mode checks are double",

So you mean in production, there's no more double check?

Comment: Well that's what I wanted to achieve but this condition doesn't work so I thought the fact that the condition was executed twice was something I needed to fix first. I also tried `"environment.id == currentServer.environment.id` but it doesn't work

Comment: In production mode change detection is only run once. 
[https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/)

`[selected]="environment.id===currentServer.environment.id"` should work, if not are you sure that currentServer.environment is not undefined?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check a change detection, you can use `stateChanges` ([here](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#directives)):

*Stream that emits whenever the state of the control changes such that the parent MatFormField needs to run change detection.*